# Django, changed data model before app converted to south

Tags: django, migration

We all love South migration in django, normally you first use `convert_to_south` and then make model class changes, then run `schemamigration` and `migrate`

I am not sure if the following scenario has happened to anyone, the project is not tracked under version control (git stash would be awesome), you changed the model class so much and lost the undo/redo history, and you realised the app has not yet converted to south. Is there a command to remedy this?

Comment: Do your text editor have some kind of log history? I user PyCharm and it's been really useful its File Log option.

Comment: Just a thought - can you get the tables that syncdb created (sql from the app) and build a model based out of that ?

Comment: @PauloBu if I use vim and closed the file I lose all the history.

Comment: @karthikr you actually can, and in theory it should work too. I haven't tried though.

Comment: Do you want just the updated models or do you just want to revertback?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea.. read all the disclaimers here first, like which databases are supported for detecting FKs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb

Update: the real answer is to use a mix of the bottom two ideas. Basically, inspectdb is a nice human readable way to figure out the difference between your model and the database. Then, I'd manually build alter table statements to match. Luckily, `sqlall` outputs the create statements, so most of it will be cut and paste for new fields.

Make a backup of everything.

1. Copy your models.py somewhere.
2. Type in `python manage.py inspectdb`
3. Find the model you're looking for and paste it into the original models.py
4. Set up south.
5. Paste the new / updated models.py back into your models.py
6. Run schemamigration then migrate.

You can also just do the migrations manually, then convert to south.

1. `python manage.py dbshell`
2. Describe table (depends on your db)
3. Find missing rows... use alter table statements as necessary. (SQL hints in `python manage.py sqlall <myapp>`

Comment: +1 for `inspectdb`. I didn't know about it. Although it doesn't work completely great because for example: treat FileFields as CharFields, as well as EmailFields etc. But still is a great piece of tool :)

Comment: @PaoloBu, nice find! Indeed, it ain't ideal. Why no VCS is the real question I think

Comment: Lol, indeed, version control is extremely useful. The first thing I checked when saw your answer was that (Those Fields that are CharFields at the end but have their tweaks) Because I was going to suggest to do that manually and thought about it. Didn't know about `inspectdb` :)

Comment: Yes inspectdb works pretty well, I have used it to migrate data from mysql to postgres. @PauloBu it doesn't really matter if it converts to CharField even originally is other field type, you just need to get the models file and run convert_to_south and then disgard the generated models file after that.